# Why my data won't save to SQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, daterangepicker

I'm quite new to Ruby on Rails. I'll just playing around with it. Actually, i'm trying to create a form with a title and a Daterangepick (bootstrap).

So, everything works fine until now. But i have one problem: My data don't save in the database. Everytime i submit the form it creates a new record, inserts automatically the "created_at" etc. But my two fields "title" and "date" are empty every time... i really don't know where my fault is. May someone of you can help me? Pls give me an answer with an explication, cause i'm really trying to understand whats going on.

Here is my code (I'm using simple_form gem)

new.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for @event do |f| %>
    <%= f.input_field :title, required: false %>
    <%= f.input :date, input_html: { class: "daterange" }, required: false %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[class="string optional daterange"]').daterangepicker(
        {
          locale: {
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
          },
          startDate: '2013-01-01',
          endDate: '2013-12-31'
        },
        function(start, end, label) {
          alert("A new date range was chosen: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        });
  });
</script>
```

events_controller.rb:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @event = Event.all
  end

  def show

  end

  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)

    if @event.save
      redirect_to @event
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
  def event_params
    params.permit(:title, :date)

  end
end
```

I think this should be enough... for sure i can post more of my code if you wish, but i think the problem has to be here somewhere, since everything works fine... it routes fines, i can insert, it redirects me to /events/:id ... just the database keeps beeing empty. Thank you for your help !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `require` in your params:

```
  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:title, :date)
  end
```

Comment: Thanks men!!! That solved my problem!
But really bizarre... i swear 2 hour ago i had it with this .require exactly the way you wrote it now... and i got an error. Now it works. Sadly, i don't know what i changed in the last two hours... But don't matter, thanks anyways!